# Automatically resize fixed image, to fit under content

Tags: javascript, html, css

Okay, so I have a simple one page website, that has content in div at top, and then an image at bottom. This image needs to be fixed to bottom, and it needs to automatically resize to fit under the div above.

Any ideas on what would be a good way to do this? If I just set the image to:

```
img {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

it works at first, but on smaller screens, the image just covers the div above. 
Setting max-height on image doesnt work either, as the div above the image sometimes covers 40% of the screens, and other times it covers 80% of screen.

Any ideas at all on what else I can try?

Comment: Do you have fiddle or provide ur site ?

Comment: Can you please create an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem so, we can help you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
img {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px); # replace 50px with your "div above" height
}
```

Comment: Okay, but what if div above is not fixed height? :/

Comment: Then you should use javascript to udate img's height or you can find out the highest value of the div above set it to div's css. :v